# Finite series manipulation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

Most of the questions I've seen on here about resources ask about good resources for understanding infinite series, but I was wondering if anyone could recommend a good source for manipulating the indices of finite series, such as how to handle double sums, and how to handle derivatives and integrals of finite series. I'm currently studying maximum likelihood estimation and expected value calculations, and the proofs therein perform odd manipulations with series that baffle me.

An example is the following, where the decomposition of the squared term in the first line into a double sum sort of makes sense to me in hindsight, but isn't something I would have come up with on my own. Other examples are converting series to matrix form, which I never quite understand. Can anyone recommend any comprehensive resources about these topics? Thanks in advance!

[image: Link to confusing series]

Answer (score 1):

We do have tricks in manipulating finite series, but those kinds of manipulation are occasional and casewise. 
Regarding your reference, "double sums" or anything is not the trick here. It is just the author was so lazy( or with other specific intention) to tell you that what he was doing is the following formula: $$Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$$ for $X, Y$ independent.